Why does one of my GAM responses not fit the data well?
I am working with this data set:
dput(Data2)
structure(list(ID = c("H4 22-jul 35-45", "H4 2-aug 40-50", "H4 2-aug 45-50", 
"H4 2-aug 50-55", "H4 2-aug 55-60", "H4 9-sep 65-70", "H4 9-sep 70-75", 
"3 aug 30-35", "3 aug 35-40", "3aug 40-45", "3aug 50-55", "3 aug 55-60", 
"3 aug 45-50", "5 aug 45-50", "9 sep 60-65", "15 sep 60-65", 
"15 sep 65-70", "15 sep 70-75", "22 Jul 25-30", "2 Aug 35-40"
), Station = c("H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "H4", "B1", "B1", "B1", "H4", 
"H4"), Date = structure(c(18830, 18841, 18841, 18841, 18841, 
18879, 18879, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18842, 18844, 
18879, 18885, 18885, 18885, 18830, 18841), class = "Date"), Class = c("35-45", 
"40-50", "45-50", "50-55", "55-60", "65-70", "70-75", "30-35", 
"35-40", "40-45", "50-55", "55-60", "45-50", "45-50", "60-65", 
"60-65", "65-70", "70-75", "25-30", "35-40"), `Fat%` = c(2.21, 
2.29, 2.89, 2.56, 2.61, 3.56, 3.61, 0.011299435, 0.01800738, 
0.019757689, 0.020450697, 0.018696884, 0.021442085, 0.02685624, 
0.034814475, 0.020908837, 0.025825371, 0.023484848, 0.044, 4.05
), Fat = c(0.022, 0.023, 0.029, 0.026, 0.026, 0.036, 0.036, 0.011, 
0.018, 0.02, 0.02, 0.019, 0.021, 0.027, 0.035, 0.021, 0.026, 
0.023, 0.044, 0.041), `<U+2211> WHO 2005 TEQdiox` = c("0.18-1.1", 
"0.27-0.31", "0.074-0.18", "0.063-0.15", "0.073-0.17", "0.078-0.14", 
"0.044-0.13", "0.74-2.0", "0.013-0.36", "0.018-0.27", "0.052-0.24", 
"0.14-0.28", "0.12-0.58", "0.087-0.97", "0.15-0.32", "0.025-0.27", 
"0.028-0.20", "0.032-0.30", "0-6.3", "0-3.0"), TEQ_DIOX_LOW_FW = c(0.18, 
0.27, 0.074, 0.063, 0.073, 0.078, 0.044, 0.74, 0.013, 0.018, 
0.052, 0.14, 0.12, 0.087, 0.15, 0.025, 0.028, 0.032, 0, 0), TEQ_DIOX_LOW_FAT = c(8.14479638, 
11.79039301, 2.560553633, 2.4609375, 2.796934866, 2.191011236, 
1.218836565, 65.49, 0.72192623, 0.911037736, 2.542700637, 7.487878788, 
5.596470588, 3.239470588, 4.308552632, 1.195666667, 1.084205128, 
1.362580645, 0, 0), TEQ_DIOX_HIGH_FW = c(1.1, 0.31, 0.18, 0.15, 
0.17, 0.14, 0.13, 2, 0.36, 0.27, 0.24, 0.28, 0.58, 0.97, 0.32, 
0.27, 0.2, 0.3, 6.3, 3), TEQ_DIOX_HIGH_FAT = c(49.77375566, 13.5371179, 
6.228373702, 5.859375, 6.513409962, 3.93258427, 3.601108033, 
177, 19.99180328, 13.66556604, 11.7355414, 14.97575758, 27.04960784, 
36.11823529, 9.191578947, 12.9132, 7.744322344, 12.77419355, 
143.1818182, 74.07407407), `S WHO 2005 TEQPCB` = c("0.29-0.32", 
"0.12", "0.17", "0.13", "0.18", "0.091", "0.086", "0.34", "0.088", 
"0.06", "0.17", "0.18", "0.32", "0.14", "0.14", "0.091", "0.11", 
"0.12", "0.51-0.61", "0.29-0.32"), TEQ_PCB_LOW_FW = c(0.29, 0.12, 
0.17, 0.13, 0.18, 0.091, 0.086, 0.34, 0.088, 0.06, 0.17, 0.18, 
0.32, 0.14, 0.14, 0.091, 0.11, 0.12, 0.51, 0.29), TEQ_PCB_LOW_FAT = c(13.12217195, 
5.240174672, 5.882352941, 5.078125, 6.896551724, 2.556179775, 
2.382271468, 30.09, 4.886885246, 3.036792453, 8.312675159, 9.627272727, 
14.92392157, 5.212941176, 4.021315789, 4.352226667, 4.259377289, 
5.109677419, 11.59090909, 7.160493827), TEQ_PCB_HIGH_FW = c(0.32, 
0.12, 0.17, 0.13, 0.18, 0.091, 0.086, 0.34, 0.088, 0.06, 0.17, 
0.18, 0.32, 0.14, 0.14, 0.091, 0.11, 0.12, 0.61, 0.32), TEQ_PCB_HIGH_FAT = c(14.47963801, 
5.240174672, 5.882352941, 5.078125, 6.896551724, 2.556179775, 
2.382271468, 30.09, 4.886885246, 3.036792453, 8.312675159, 9.627272727, 
14.92392157, 5.212941176, 4.021315789, 4.352226667, 4.259377289, 
5.109677419, 13.86363636, 7.901234568), `<U+2211> WHO 2005 TEQ` = c("0.47-1.4", 
"0.39-0.43", "0.24-0.34", "0.20-0.29", "0.25-0.35", "0.17-0.23", 
"0.13-0.22", "1.1-2.3", "0.10-0.45", "0.078-0.33", "0.22-0.41", 
"0.32-0.46", "0.44-0.90", "0.23-1.1", "0.29-0.46", "0.12-0.36", 
"0.14-0.31", "0.15-0.42", "0.51-6.9", "0.29-3.3"), TEQ_ALL_LOW_FW = c(0.47, 
0.39, 0.24, 0.2, 0.25, 0.17, 0.13, 1.1, 0.1, 0.078, 0.22, 0.32, 
0.44, 0.23, 0.29, 0.12, 0.14, 0.15, 0.51, 0.29), TEQ_ALL_LOW_FAT = c(21.26696833, 
17.03056769, 8.30449827, 7.8125, 9.578544061, 4.775280899, 3.601108033, 
97.35, 5.553278689, 3.947830189, 10.75757962, 17.11515152, 20.52039216, 
8.564117647, 8.329868421, 5.7392, 5.421025641, 6.387096774, 11.59090909, 
7.160493827), TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW = c(1.4, 0.43, 0.34, 0.29, 0.35, 
0.23, 0.22, 2.3, 0.45, 0.33, 0.41, 0.46, 0.9, 1.1, 0.46, 0.36, 
0.31, 0.42, 6.9, 3.3), TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FAT = c(63.34841629, 18.77729258, 
11.76470588, 11.328125, 13.40996169, 6.460674157, 6.094182825, 
203.55, 24.9897541, 16.70235849, 20.04821656, 24.6030303, 41.97352941, 
40.95882353, 13.21289474, 17.2176, 12.00369963, 17.88387097, 
156.8181818, 81.48148148), tp = c(NA, NA, 2.92894736842105, 2.92631578947368, 
2.80526315789474, 2.89539473684211, 2.87105263157895, 2.78684210526316, 
2.86184210526316, 2.86644736842105, 2.83289473684211, 2.84473684210526, 
2.84473684210526, 2.84473684210526, 2.89144736842105, 2.89473684210526, 
2.85921052631579, 2.85657894736842, 2.64868421052632, 2.74605263157895
), growth = c(NA, NA, 0.205765929186115, NA, NA, 0.262244047285399, 
0.269171364150501, 0.195624303507787, 0.191379798732832, 0.173724801061008, 
0.234761502687199, 0.245258784062335, 0.234593615855829, 0.234593615855829, 
0.267767546441371, 0.251100958196473, 0.260895198720363, NA, 
0.111781086041946, 0.173705402650357), Sizenum = c(40, 42.5, 
47.5, 52.5, 57.5, 67.5, 72.5, 32.5, 37.5, 42.5, 52.5, 57.5, 47.5, 
47.5, 62.5, 62.5, 67.5, 72.5, 27.5, 37.5), Month = c(7, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
> 

I have run multiple GAM's and the one with the best fit is:
gam4 <- mgcv::gam(TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW ~ s(tp, k = 5) + s(growth, k = 5), data = Data2)

with the results:
> summary(gam4)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW ~ s(tp, k = 5) + s(growth, k = 5)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.20467    0.06797   17.72 6.31e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
            edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(tp)     2.924  3.406 67.402 2.72e-06 ***
s(growth) 1.000  1.000  0.279    0.609    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.979   Deviance explained = 98.5%
GCV = 0.10316  Scale est. = 0.0693    n = 15

When I look at the plots, the tp variable looks great:
plot_predictions(gam4, condition = c('tp'), type = "response", points = 1, draw = TRUE)+
  theme_classic()


but the growth variable does not have a good fit at all:
plot_predictions(gam4, condition = c('growth'), type = "response", points = 1)


I understand that the variable is being penalized to a simple linear predictor as told by the edf=1, but why does the linear line have such an awful fit?
I honestly did not expect the growth variable to be penalized to a linear predictor, and even so, I expected the linear line to have much more of a negative slope.  Is the first data point being penalized or is something similar happening?

You are misinterpreting these plots. The points show the original data and the lines are marginal effects. You should infer from these plots that the tp smoother models the data quite well on its own and that the growth smoother doesn't contribute much to the fit. In fact, you should allow the model to shrink that smoother to zero edf:
gam4a <- gam(TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW ~ s(tp, k = 5) + s(growth, k = 5), 
               data = Data2, select = TRUE)

summary(gam4a)
# Family: gaussian 
# Link function: identity 
# 
# Formula:
# TEQ_ALL_HIGH_FW ~ s(tp, k = 5) + s(growth, k = 5)
# 
# Parametric coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  1.20467    0.06371   18.91 6.33e-10 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#                 edf Ref.df   F p-value    
# s(tp)     2.670e+00      4 180  <2e-16 ***
# s(growth) 1.843e-10      4   0   0.691    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# R-sq.(adj) =  0.981   Deviance explained = 98.5%
# GCV = 0.080605  Scale est. = 0.060886  n = 15

Note the very high explained deviance and the very small edf and large p-value of the growth smoother.
There are collinearity issues with your predictors, so it is not surprising that one of them gets shrunk so much:
plot(tp ~ growth, data = Data2)


with(Data2, cor(tp, growth, use = "complete.obs"))
#[1] 0.7403158


You don't have a large sample size, so you wont be able to accurately estimate very flexible curves.  Nevertheless, here are a few things you can try:

gam.check(): this will run some diagnostics to check whether k=5 is enough.  It probably is, but good to double check.
concurvity() this will check for collinearity between the curves, an issue that @Roland raised.  You can look at the help page for more details.  Some interpret a concurvity > 0.8 as a problem, although others in the thread cite a more liberal cutoff of 0.5.
I also second @Roland's recommendation to use select which applies a type of penalization/variable selection procedure.
Lastly, your adjusted $R^2$ = 0.979 is super high/great, and like Roland said, it's mostly driven by tp and growth barely has any effect.  Thus you could consider a model that only has tp since growth doesn't really seem needed.

